# Change Windows Update behaviour based on internet connection type

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Generally I don't mind updaters leeching my bandwidth, but it hurts when I am on mobile data. Is it possible to set Windows update to download updates only when I am on the fixed line internet, without having to change the update settings. (one obvious distinction is that DSL is a LAN connection and packet data is a dialup connection, so maybe we can exploit it somehow)

Or if I can define a rule allowing only my web browser and download manager to use the dial-up connection, that will simplify life and improve karma.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable Updates for Windows.
2. Monitor internet activity through a program.
3. Find how to capture output with batch.
4. Run batch to enable the Windows Update.
5. Make batch receive an answer of Windows Update.
6. Close Windows Update.

You can read a few Tech Forums or Blogs to find something related.

Running a search with those the terms : *windows* *update* *internet* *bandwidtdh* gave me top answers that are more than likely to solve your issue.